# selenium firefox webdriver doesn't make a complete download of a PDF with python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, anaconda

I'm trying to download a PDF with python, from a java event not html, and I already changed my firefox preferences, it makes the download but when I try to open the file it says that the file must be damaged or corrupt, I noted that when firefox webdriver makes the download, it doesn't download all the bytes of it so I don't know if it doesn't wait till the download is complete or if there's something I'm missing in my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2) 
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/pdf")
fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled",True)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Users\\carlo\\Desktop\\
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get(the url which i cant give here)
```

Then I open a new window in the code and take control of it which is a PDF web window, and use this:

```
element= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).\until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='download']")))
element.click()
```

Additional to this, it doesn't have a URL; it's a java event that doesn't come with that and now it starts the download but it corrupts it. I have tried to wait with `time.sleep` but it still has the same problem. If there's a way to set a preference of direct download without opening a new window with the driver it should help, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already figured it out just needed to add time in the element.click.sleep(2)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can verify if the file has been downloaded before quiting the browser:

```
import glob
import time

download_dir = "C:\\Users\\carlo\\Desktop"

def still_downloading(download_dir):
        files = glob.glob(download_dir+"/*.part")

        if len(files) > 0:
            return True

        return False

...
element.click()

while still_downloading(dl_location):
      print "still downloading..."
      time.sleep(1)
```

This way you don't have to "guess" the time needed to download your file beforehand.